# GraphQL with express error : Query.example field type must be Output Type but got: [object Object]

Tags: node.js, graphql

I'm trying to run express server with graphql and I get the following error:

> Error: Query.example field type must be Output Type but got: [object Object].

express-graphql used in a route:

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP(req => ({
 schema,
 pretty: true
})));
```

The schema looks like that:

```
export default new GraphQLSchema({
 query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: queries
 })
});
```

Queries has only one query that imported from here:

```
import {
 GraphQLList,
 GraphQLID,
 GraphQLNonNull
} from 'graphql';

import exampleScheme from '../models/schemes/example';
import {example as exampleData}  from '../models/jsons'

export default {
 type: exampleScheme,
 resolve (root, params, options) {
     return exampleData;
 }
};
```

The schemas (exampleScheme) and data (exampleScheme) are working on another project so I assume they're not the problem.

Any ideas? What does 'Output type' mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if

```
export default {
 type: exampleScheme,
 resolve (root, params, options) {
     return exampleData;
 }
};
```

is your queries, then you got it wrong,
Query's fields, hence queries in your example, should be looking like this:

```
export default {
 helloString: {
     type: GraphQLString,
     resolve (root, params, options) {
         return "Hello World!";
     }
 }
 ... <Next query>
};
```

anyway, the error is that 'type' is not a valid GraphQLType.
then the query will look like this

```
query {
   testString
}
```

will result in:

```
{
    testString: "Hello World!"
}
```

if the meaning was that the exampleScheme is some other object,
please make sure you are creating it using:

```
new GraphQLObjectType({ .... Options });
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks HagaiCo, because I imported the schemes from another project, exmaple scheme was a 'GraphQLSchema' instead of 'GraphQLObjectType'.