# GraphQL Cross References throws error: field type must be Output Type but got: [object Object]

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am struggleing at the moment with my GraphQL API and unfortunately it is not working because I get always the error message:

```
Error: Contact.other field type must be Output Type but got: [object Object].
```

I still read some articles and posts, like [GraphQL with express error : Query.example field type must be Output Type but got: [object Object]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496372/graphql-with-express-error-query-example-field-type-must-be-output-type-but-go), but it does not work anyway because the answers does not solve the error reason in my case. I hope you can help me or just give me a hint to solve this problem. I attached the main parts of my code below:

ProfileType.js:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const ContactType = require('./ContactType');
const ObjectType = graphql.GraphQLObjectType;
const List = graphql.GraphQLListType;
const ID = graphql.GraphQLID;
const NonNull = graphql.GraphQLNonNull;

const ProfileType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'Profile',
  fields: function () {
    return {
      id: {type: new NonNull(ID)},
      contacts: {type: new List(ContactType)},
    };
  },
});

module.exports = ProfileType;
```

ContactType.js:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const ProfileType = require('./ProfileType');
const ObjectType = graphql.GraphQLObjectType;
const EnumType = graphql.GraphQLEnumType;

const ContactType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'Contact',
  fields: function () {
    return {
      other: {
        type: ProfileType
      },
      status: {
        type: new EnumType({
          values: {
            REQUESTED: {value: 0},
            COMMITTED: {value: 1}
          },
          name: 'ContactStatus'
        })
      }
    };
  },
});

module.exports = ContactType;
```

Comment: Why are you with ContactType using ProfileType and ContactType with ProfileType. Shouldn't this circular refference causing an inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: I thought normally circular behavior should work with GraphQL. I wanted to Modell that a person is in contact with several other persons. Those persons should all have also a profile. In the end I would like to get all e.g. all ids and names of the contacts of one person. Those parameters are part of the ProfileType and therefore no extra ObjectType is required (avoid redundancy). Or is such a circulatory not possible with GraphQL?

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

Solved it by moving the required ObjectType to the fields function:

```
const ContactType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'Contact',
  fields: function () {
    const ProfileType = require('./ProfileType');
    // ...
  }
});
```

Otherwise, the ObjectType has problems with the circularity. The same have to be done of course with the ProfileType.